# Modify CSV Date/Time Column Data on ImportCSV function

Tags: date, google-apps-script, time

running a script to import a csv from gmail attachment into a Google Sheet and there is a timestamp column.

We are looking to modify those value to be just Date and remove the timestamp before writing the csv contents into the Google Sheet.

Any tips on how we might do that? We're very much beginners here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your code and the result you're expecting to achieve.

Comment: I would try using [Utilities.parseCSV](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char)) to get it into a 2D Array and go down the timestamp column with [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) converting each one to a date and then use [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to load it into the spreadsheet.  Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

As the function name says this function accepts a CSV string and converts it to a 2D Array. It then iterates down column  1 removing the time part of the datetime and then it loads a sheet.

```
function getCSVConvertToArrayRemoveTimeAndLoadSheet(csv) {
  var csv=csv||getCSV();
  var vA=Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    vA[i][0]=new Date(new Date(vA[i][0]).getFullYear(),new Date(vA[i][0]).getMonth(),new Date(vA[i][0]).getDate());
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet178');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length);
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

I used the below function to create CSV String from a simple spreadsheet with column 1 as a timestamp.

```
function getCSV() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet177');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var csv="";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(i>0) csv+='\n';
    csv+=vA[i].join(',');
  }
  //Logger.log(csv);
  return csv;
}
```

[Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))